# Xbox One S vs. Xbox One X - multimedia / user interface performance

Tags: xbox-one

I used to have an Xbox One S, which was, at times, rather sluggish when navigating through menus and using Kodi to stream content from my PC.

Does the Xbox One X fare better at such tasks thanks to its higher GPU clock and much faster and larger RAM?

Comment: Don't bother with X1X - buy the latest generation Xbox Series X.

Comment: @iBug I was considering that as well, but I'll mostly use it for multimedia anyway. So it's 100 / 150$ vs. 300 / 500$.